# Count frequency of array objects by key

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, filter

I have an array of students like this:

```
    var school =[ 
    {
    class: "ss1",
    student: "J. Kent",
    scores: "accurate"
},
{
    class: "ss1",
    student: "P. Ben",
    scores: "accurate"
},
{
    class: "ss3",
    student: "T. Maddison",
    scores: "error"
},
{
    class: "jss1",
    student: "R Briggs",
    scores: "accurate"
},
{
    class: "ss1",
    student: "P. Roberts",
    scores: "accurate"
},
{
    class: "ss1",
    student: "A. Minder",
    scores: "error"
},
{
    class: "ss1",
    student: "C. Trust",
    scores: "accurate"
},

]
```

I want to count the number of times someone belonging to `class: "ss1"` `scores: "accurate"` occurred.
I've looked around for libraries to make this easy, but could not lay hands on one.
Any method or simpler approach is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to filter the values and get its length.

```js
var school=[{class:"ss1",student:"J. Kent",scores:"accurate"},{class:"ss1",student:"P. Ben",scores:"accurate"},{class:"ss3",student:"T. Maddison",scores:"error"},{class:"jss1",student:"R Briggs",scores:"accurate"},{class:"ss1",student:"P. Roberts",scores:"accurate"},{class:"ss1",student:"A. Minder",scores:"error"},{class:"ss1",student:"C. Trust",scores:"accurate"}];

console.log(school.filter(scl => scl.class === 'ss1' && scl.scores === 'accurate').length)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

```js
const school = [
  {
    class: "ss1",
    student: "J. Kent",
    scores: "accurate",
  },
  {
    class: "ss1",
    student: "P. Ben",
    scores: "accurate",
  },
  {
    class: "ss3",
    student: "T. Maddison",
    scores: "error",
  },
  {
    class: "jss1",
    student: "R Briggs",
    scores: "accurate",
  },
  {
    class: "ss1",
    student: "P. Roberts",
    scores: "accurate",
  },
  {
    class: "ss1",
    student: "A. Minder",
    scores: "error",
  },
  {
    class: "ss1",
    student: "C. Trust",
    scores: "accurate",
  },
];


const getResults = (group, score) => {
  return school.filter((obj) => obj.class === group && obj.scores === score).length;
}

const result = getResults("ss1", "accurate");

console.log(result);
```

Or [array.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

```js
const school = [
  {
    class: "ss1",
    student: "J. Kent",
    scores: "accurate",
  },
  {
    class: "ss1",
    student: "P. Ben",
    scores: "accurate",
  },
  {
    class: "ss3",
    student: "T. Maddison",
    scores: "error",
  },
  {
    class: "jss1",
    student: "R Briggs",
    scores: "accurate",
  },
  {
    class: "ss1",
    student: "P. Roberts",
    scores: "accurate",
  },
  {
    class: "ss1",
    student: "A. Minder",
    scores: "error",
  },
  {
    class: "ss1",
    student: "C. Trust",
    scores: "accurate",
  },
];


const getResults = (group, score) => {
  return school.reduce((count, obj) => obj.class === group && obj.scores === score ? ++count : count, 0);
}

const result = getResults("ss1", "accurate");

console.log(result);
```